# Granting access to tables from a database link to a local database

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges, sql-grant

I'm currently in the middle of a project that requires me to write a SQL script for creating a local database. In my code, I've created a database link to our development database I've created the users needed. In order for me to pass all unit test, I need to provide access to the specific tables needed from my database link. When I run all unit test, the only errors being thrown are 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'. How can I grant access to these tables for the user xxltbpg from the local database link?

Here's the code that I have written so far:

```
--Drop Database--
drop database link DEV_LINK;

--Create database link--

create database link DEV_LINK
  connect to user
  identified by pass
  using '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = usnodev) (PORT = 1531))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = DEV))) '; 

--Create Users for LWS-

CREATE USER xxlt IDENTIFIED BY user;

--Create Users for BPG--

CREATE USER xxltbpg IDENTIFIED BY user;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO xxltbpg;
--Grant access to tables from local database--
```

Answer (score 1):

While I was searching for your issue I find this question has been already asked use this link , if it could help

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13074/how-to-grant-permission-on-a-table-to-a-user-on-the-other-database-in-oracle